# Laravel 5.6 Passport Limit Failed Login Attempts with ThrottlesLogins

Tags: php, laravel, rest, api, authentication

I have an API based Laravel application which uses [Passport](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/passport) for api authentication.I uses passport **oauth/toke** route for login.I want to restrict the user with three consecutive failed login attempts and block the user for one minute.

I have seen following links for help like that were near to my problem.

1. [Laravel 5.6 Passport OAuth Max Login Attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49803119/laravel-5-6-passport-oauth-max-login-attempts).
2. https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/693

The above two solution implement login functionality in **AuthController** and this is not working for me. I want to use **ThrottlesLogins** trait to be used in **AccessTokenController** and restrict the user.

Here is another one which seems like it can work but is also not according to my need .

https://github.com/laravel/passport/issues/217

Can any one help to solve this problem.?

Comment: Did you resolve this?